# no permission on wp_admin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-hosting

I installed the latest version of wordpress in my hosting server. How ever I was not able to add any media. I checked the server space and I have still of huge free space. And then I try to access settings --> media , I got this error

**You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

I added the this into my .htaccess file but still no luck

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas?

-Alan-

Comment: I had permissions issues with some of the files after I updated last night. I'd check there first.  You might try http://wordpress.shadowlantern.com/how-to-fix-permissions-on-files-and-directories/

Answer (score 0):

You must download Filezilla and put permissions 755 on every WP file inside your hosting. Also, if this don't work, try to remove all plugins, maybe some plugin is causing the problem.